# High Sierra Preventing Boot Into Ubuntu with rEFInd

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, macosx, refind

I updated to macOS High Sierra a few days ago - I now realize this was a mistake as I can no longer access the rEFInd boot menu at startup and launch Ubuntu. I'm stuck on macOS and can't access anything on my Ubuntu boot. Good thing I pushed code before the update. How do I fix this?

Can I reinstall rEFInd without messing up access to my Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to reinstall rEFInd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty thanks @MichaelBay for the help! Reinstalling rEFInd was indeed the solution. I'll leave this here for anyone else having problems with High Sierra.